Converting old eslint.json to flat eslint.js for custom eslint rules
Previously I got my projects configured this way by using the extend attribute:
    {
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["**/*"],
  "plugins": ["@nx"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {
        "@nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
          "error",
          {
            "enforceBuildableLibDependency": true,
            "allow": [],
            "depConstraints": [
              {
                "sourceTag": "*",
                "onlyDependOnLibsWithTags": ["*"]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nx/typescript"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nx/javascript"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.spec.ts", "*.spec.tsx", "*.spec.js", "*.spec.jsx"],
      "env": {
        "jest": true
      },
      "rules": {}
    }
  ],
  "extends": "./eslintrc-custom-rules.json"
}

my eslintrc-custom-rules.json looked like this:
{
"overrides": [
    {
    "files": ["*.ts"],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": "error",

        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "error",

        "default-case": "error",
        "default-case-last": "error"
    },
    "extends": "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    },
    {
    "files": ["*.html"],
    "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/attributes-order": ["error"],

        "@angular-eslint/template/no-duplicate-attributes": ["error"]

    },
    "extends": "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    }
]
}

Now I want to convert that "eslintrc-custom-rules.json" into a flat .js file in order to fit into this auto generated code of NX version 18+
const nx = require('@nx/eslint-plugin');

module.exports = [
  ...nx.configs['flat/base'],
  ...nx.configs['flat/typescript'],
  ...nx.configs['flat/javascript'],
  {
    ignores: ['**/dist'],
  },
  {
    files: ['**/*.ts', '**/*.tsx', '**/*.js', '**/*.jsx'],
    // Override or add rules here
    rules: {},
  },
  ...nx.configs['flat/angular'],
  ...nx.configs['flat/angular-template'],
  {
    files: ['**/*.ts'],
    rules: {
      '@angular-eslint/directive-selector': [
        'error',
        {
          type: 'attribute',
          prefix: 'app',
          style: 'camelCase',
        },
      ],
      '@angular-eslint/component-selector': [
        'error',
        {
          type: 'element',
          prefix: 'app',
          style: 'kebab-case',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    files: ['**/*.html'],
    // Override or add rules here
    rules: {},
  },
];

How do I achieve that? Bings Copilot can not help me, there are no existing forum questions, so I'm asking here now.

I found a solution... Just need to add what is listed here https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration-new-eslintconfigjs
const eslintPluginPrettierRecommended = require('eslint-plugin-prettier/recommended');
    
module.exports = [
  // Any other config imports go at the top
  eslintPluginPrettierRecommended,
];

